# Cmake и переменные среды

Tags: cmake

Как в `CMakeLists.txt` взять переменную среды?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26336049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью [`ENV`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/variable/ENV.html). Например, если нужно получить значение `$HOME`, делаем так: `$ENV{HOME}`

Comment: Есть еще такой вопрос: как передать переменную среды от компилятора в CMakeLists.txt? Дело в том, что у меня кросскомпиляция и компилятор то знает нужные переменные, а cmake использует переменные из линукса.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch наверное, это лучше оформить отдельным вопросом, с конкретным примером, чего Вы хотите достичь.